# Java: Including spaces when finding the length of the string

Tags: java, string, comparison

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
String a = input.next();

System.out.println("Please enter another string: ");
String b = input2.next();

int s1 = a.length();
int s2 = b.length();
int i;

if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
   System.out.println(a.substring(i = 0, i + s2));
}
```

I'm trying to compare 2 strings that are input by the user. The string comparison is working fine, however, when I input a string with spaces like
"i like dogs," it counts the string length as 1 instead of 11 because of the space between "i" and "like." Why is the program not counting the spaces or the remaining characters after the first space?

Comment: use `input.nextLine();`

Comment: `input.next()` get's the next complete token, delimited by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**next() method** returns the next token if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.

**nextLine() method** advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

if not you can use bellow code of **java.io** package

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter a string");
String s = br.readLine();
System.out.println(s.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

When using input.next(), whitespace is considered a delimiter that separates the tokens accepted by the scanner. So when the scanner reads in your sentence "i like dogs" it finds 3 separate tokens separated by the whitespace. You can either specify a delimiter using the useDelimiter method of the scanner class such as

```
scanner scan = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(insert parameters here);
```

or just use the input.nextLine() method that reads in the entire line as the accepted token.

```
String b = input.nextLine();
```